# How to avoid to declare the same type two different times in function header and body when dealing with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types

I wrote this function that returns the mean of the values in the range delimited by two iterators:

```
template<class InputIterator>
typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<InputIterator>())>::type mean (InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
  return std::accumulate(first, last, typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<InputIterator>())>::type ()) / std::distance(first, last);
}
```

The value type, which is both used internally and returned, is deduced from the iterator. Since the syntax for the type deduction is quite heavy I was wondering if there is a way to avoid to use it twice.

I know that I may add a second template parameter and set its default to the value type, but I'm not convinced since one may specify a different value type and I would like to preclude this possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to form a generic typedef for `yourType`

```
template<class InIt>
using yourType = typename decay<decltype(*declval<InIt>())>::type;

template<class InIt>
yourType<InIt> mean(InIt first, InIt last) 
{
    return accumulate(first, last, yourType<InIt>()) / distance(first, last);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/KnLFxu)

Comment: `yourType` is actually a `value_type`.

Comment: @Constructor Have I said elseway ? Edit : This affects the answer how ? (I'm supposing you mean it's a value type when instantiated right ?)

Comment: No, it is only a comment.

Comment: Variadic templates are fine, but to me they seem an overkill here. I think that aliases better suite this case.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid user to change the default type, you may add a variadic tamplate

```
template <typename InputIterator,
        typename...,
        typename Type = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<InputIterator>())>::type
    >
Type mean (InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    return std::accumulate(first, last, Type()) / std::distance(first, last);
}
```

or even more secure to avoid to provide more template argument to `mean`.

```
template <typename InputIterator,
        typename...DummyTs,
        typename Type = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<InputIterator>())>::type,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(DummyTs) == 0>::type
    >
Type mean (InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    return std::accumulate(first, last, Type()) / std::distance(first, last);
}
```